# Dropbox sync across LAN - Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, sync, lan, dropbox

I've got Dropbox installed on both my Windows 7 machine and my Ubuntu machine.  I've got "Enable LAN sync" ticked on both.

However it doesn't seem to be syncing via the LAN.  Is it possible to sync across a LAN across different OSes with Dropbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible of course but Dropbox behaves stupid sometimes. Try out the experimental build, Ubuntu needs that one I guess. Just unpack it and start the dropbox file.

[Here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=19866) is the official forum thread for experimental builds.